# want to insert single records into two tables from single controller file

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, model, controller

In the `listing` controller, I have a function named `admin_edit` which updates records in the `listing` table, `cache_popularcities` column by `listing id`.

In this function, I want to also update `listing_asset` table, `cache_popularcities` column by `listing id`, which is not updated and changed; `listing_asset` is a different model and controller file.

**admin_edit**

```
class ListingsController extends AppController
{
    function admin_edit($id = null)
   {    
        if($this->data)
        {
            //listing table cache_popularcities column only changed and updated 
            $this->data['Listing']['cache_popularcities'] = 
            '-'.$this->data['Listing']['popularcities'].'-'; 

            //listing_asset table cache_popularcities column can't be changed and updated
            $this->Listing->ListingAsset->data['ListingAsset']['cache_popularcities'] 
                 = '-'.$this->data['Listing']['popularcities'].'-'; 

            if($this->save($this->data,true))
            {
               $this->ListingAsset->save($this->data,true);
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access data inside controller methods you need to use:

```
$this->request->data
```

while inside model methods use:

```
$this->data
```